# Howto set combobox to unselected at start

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using `$('#id').append(new Option(...))` to add entries to a `<select id='id' >` combobox. 
After having added some entries the combobox is already showing the first entry. However I would like to have show empty combobox in the beginning because I'm binding to the .click event and the user otherwise need to reselect the already shown item.

Comment: So append a blank option first. What have you tried? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: What combobox?  You mean a datalist? Can you please click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor to show a [mcve] with relevant HTML and script

Comment: I mean a simple <select> without a <datalist>.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
$sel = $("#sel");
$sel.append(
  $("<option/>", {
      value: "",
      text: "Please select"
  })
)
$.each(["a", "b", "c"], function(i,val) {
  $sel.append(
    $("<option/>", {
      value: val,
      text: val
    })
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel"></select>
```

OR this

```js
$sel = $("#sel");
$.each(["a", "b", "c"], function(i, val) {
  $sel.append(
    $("<option/>", {
      value: val,
      text: val
    })
  )
})
```

```css
input[name=example] {
  width: 120px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="example" list="sel" placeholder="Please select or type" />
<datalist id="sel"></datalist>
```

Comment: I was asking about <select> without a <datalist>.

Comment: Yes, it kindof works, however I dont want the "Please Select" as an explicit option. Only an empty combobox.

Comment: append: maybe that is not possible ?